# Client closing TCP connection before receiving async WCF response

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

We have a Silverlight 4.0 application that makes many calls to our WCF services.  We have lots of users and mostly it’s fine, but one user is having a problem that seems to be confined to a particular asynchronous call on a single (Windows 7) machine.  It is always reproducible, but only for that call from that machine.  The WCF request is sent but then after a pause the Silverlight app throws this:

```
Message: [HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]
Arguments: NotFound
Stack Trace:    at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at MyContractClientChannel.EndApplicationSave(IAsyncResult result)
   at MyServiceContract.EndApplicationSave(IAsyncResult result)
   at MyServiceContractClient.OnEndApplicationSave(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

The initiating call looks like this:

```
using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)Client.InnerChannel))
    {
        Client.ApplicationSaveAsync(request, callback);
    }
```

Client.ApplicationSaveAsync is the usual auto-generated code that calls System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.InvokeAsync.

When we watch the conversation with WireShark we see the request packets being sent (this takes about two seconds) followed by a delay of about ten seconds.  Then comes the weird part.  On a machine that works we see the response packets come down from the server, but on the problem machine we see the client suddenly send an empty packet with the TCP FIN flag set (before any response is received).  We can’t understand why it would do this.  When we try Fiddler instead of WireShark, Fiddler reports “Session State: Aborted”, which looks like just another interpretation of the same underlying problem (that the client has unexpectedly pulled the plug on the connection).

We would greatly appreciate any suggestions as to why this might be happening or what we can do to investigate it further.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to go away when we created a new Windows profile for the user.